# Polymorphic model serialization using Jackson

Tags: java, jackson-databind

I have to send request to a third party service where the request JSON looks similar to below. There will be another api which has the same exact JSON format as the response. So I need to build object model that will be able to successfully serialize to/ deserialize from this JSON format.

Sample json

```
{
    "name": "Johnny",
    "vehicles": [{
        "vehicleType": "car",
        "vehicleInfo": {
            "maxSeatCount": 2,
            "coupe": true
        }
    }, {
        "vehicleType": "truck",
        "vehicleInfo": {
            "towingCapacity": "3000lb",
            "bedLength": "6ft"
        }
    }]
}
```

Here are the POJOs I created to meet the above model.

**PersonInfo.java**

```
public class PersonInfo {
    private String name;
    private List<Vehicle> vehicles;
}
```

**Vehicle.java**

```
public class Vehicle {
    private String vehicleType;
    private VehicleInfo vehicleInfo;
}
```

**VehicleInfo.java**

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = Id.NAME, 
            include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY,
            property = "vehicleType")
@JsonSubTypes({
    @Type(value = CarInfo.class, name="car"),
    @Type(value = TruckInfo.class, name="truck")
})
public abstract class VehicleInfo {

}
```

**CarInfo.java**

```
public class CarInfo extends VehicleInfo{

    private int maxSeatCount;
    private boolean coupe;
}
```

**TruckInfo.java**

```
public class TruckInfo extends VehicleInfo{

    private String towingCapacity;
    private String bedLength;
}
```

I'm running into two problems with this model. During serialization, the JSON generated has the attribute `vehicleType` inside `vehicleInfo` object as well. It should not be.

JSON generated using above model.

```
{
  "name" : "Johnny",
  "vehicles" : [ {
    "vehicleType" : "car",
    "vehicleInfo" : {
      "vehicleType" : "car", // this shouldn't be here
      "maxSeatCount" : 2,
      "coupe" : false
    }
  }, {
    "vehicleType" : "truck",
    "vehicleInfo" : {
      "vehicleType" : "truck", // this shouldn't be here
      "towingCapacity" : "3000lb",
      "bedLength" : "6ft"
    }
  } ]
}
```

Second issue is that during deserialization, Jackson is complaining that it doesn't see the `vehicleType` attribute in `vehicleInfo` type.

> Exception in thread "main"
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException: Could not
> resolve subtype of [simple type, class
> com.kodakandla.file.VehicleInfo]: missing type id property
> 'vehicleType' (for POJO property 'vehicleInfo')  at [Source:
> (String)"{"name":"Johnny","vehicles":[{"vehicleType":"car","vehicleInfo":{"maxSeatCount":2,"coupe":true}},{"vehicleType":"truck","vehicleInfo":{"towingCapacity":"3000lb","bedLength":"6ft"}}]}";
> line: 1, column: 95] (through reference chain:
> com.kodakandla.file.PersonInfo["vehicles"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.kodakandla.file.Vehicle["vehicleInfo"])
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException.from(InvalidTypeIdException.java:43)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.missingTypeIdException(DeserializationContext.java:2083)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingTypeId(DeserializationContext.java:1596)

What changes do I need to make for this to work?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was wrong with my POJOs. Thought I would post the answer just in case if anyone else runs into similar issue.

I have the `@JsonTypeInfo` annotation in the wrong place. Instead of setting it at the class level in the `VehicleInfo` class, I had to set it at the field level in the `Vehicle` class.

```
public class Vehicle {

    private String vehicleType;
    
    @JsonTypeInfo(use = Id.NAME, 
            include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY,
            property = "vehicleType")
    @JsonSubTypes({
           @Type(value = CarInfo.class, name="car"),
           @Type(value = TruckInfo.class, name="truck")
    })
    private VehicleInfo vehicleInfo;
}
```

Now the serialization and deserialization are working as expected.